# Magento custom Cookie not being set

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

Hi I have added the following code to the bottom of my index.php for a seperate store view in a subfolder of my magento installation.

`$name = 'test';
$value = 'testval';
// set cookie
Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set($name, $value);
//Show Cookie
echo Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get($name);`

It isnt echoing anything and I have no cookie in chrome, does anyone know why this may be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set` method in the cookie model uses the [`setcookie`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) php function.
As you can see in the link, the cookie you set is available in the next request.

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page
>   load with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays. Note, superglobals
>   such as $_COOKIE became available in PHP 4.1.0. Cookie values also
>   exist in $_REQUEST.

You are trying to get the cookie in the same request.

Comment: I see what you mean but even after clicking to a new page the cookie does not appear in my browsers settings and still does not echo.